Why does res.text() not work inside useEffect()?
On islands/test.tsx I have:
import { useEffect } from "preact/hooks";
export default function Test(){ 
    fetch('https://example.com')
    .then(res => res.text())
    .then(d => console.log(d))
    
    useEffect(() => {        
        fetch('https://example.com')
        .then(res => res.text())
        .then(d => console.log(d))     
    })
    return 'hi'
}

The data returns fine in the server's console (the part outside the useEffect() hook), but it doesn't show up in the client's console. However if I change the fetch function to:
fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
.then(res => res.json())
.then(d => console.log(d))

then it shows on both sides. Why is that the case?

Not related to useEffect here. It works for both cases.
Why do you not see the message in the client? Because of CORS
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS
The second API (https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1) works because it public API that allows * already.
